# REST-Assured - JsonPath for fetching a list of values

Tags: java, jsonpath, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm using REST-Assured for testing some RESTful webservices. Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "status":true,
    "responseData":{
        "orderLevelReasons":[
            {
                "reasons":[
                    {
                        "reasonId":"129cfea8-b022-4dc8-9811-222a324f46aa",
                        "reasonName":"COD Amount Mismatch"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"a881fd5c-626e-438c-8026-646aa2a19098",
                        "reasonName":"Gave wrong information"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"543d438a-88cc-487c-86e4-19eecefa9ca7",
                        "reasonName":"Late delivery"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"080cd7c1-7a37-48ad-9090-57286d93ea41",
                        "reasonName":"Parcel not received"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"5ca3d9b4-0fa2-49da-a534-a6f2e7eccc07",
                        "reasonName":"Staff did not inform about the parcel arrival"
                    }
                ],
                "issueName":"ISSUE TYPE 1",
                "issueId":"0c2c37a6-62b6-4c28-ab6c-566487d045bd",
                "hint":""
            },
            {
                "reasons":[
                    {
                        "reasonId":"129cfea8-b022-4dc8-9811-222a324f46aa",
                        "reasonName":"COD Amount Mismatch"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"14975b5d-23fb-4735-8082-2e02d6335788",
                        "reasonName":"Data issue"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"7e6e8446-3774-4589-9171-8e7ab0a7f73b",
                        "reasonName":"Delivery BOY did not inform before delivering"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"543d438a-88cc-487c-86e4-19eecefa9ca7",
                        "reasonName":"Late delivery"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"080cd7c1-7a37-48ad-9090-57286d93ea41",
                        "reasonName":"Parcel not received"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"8e430c71-f28b-49e4-9946-e0bd5131768b",
                        "reasonName":"Refuse to come doorstep"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"515d0fa4-a44c-47eb-a7a2-5ddae778f37a",
                        "reasonName":"Extra Amount taken By Partner Staff"
                    }
                ],
                "issueName":"ISSUE TYPE 2",
                "issueId":"ac902377-3db2-462a-8e53-48b06d1aff1f",
                "hint":""
            }
        ],
        "productLevelReasons":[
            {
                "reasons":[
                    {
                        "reasonId":"6129dcb8-1ae5-4d7d-9c95-4c0ec2f69ded",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason1"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"febec32b-b243-4509-b46a-20d9f4747ca3",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason2"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"d8a492b8-f816-41e6-b45d-5ec29f3a0785",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason3"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"c0c98489-6401-455a-9145-f52664d8aff4",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason4"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"ef2b4147-ee76-4961-b784-63e848a84167",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason5"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"7f4f9657-17b2-407b-aed7-16b221bf3229",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason6"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"2aa83be6-60cb-43dc-9273-c41e6047315e",
                        "reasonName":"Others"
                    },
                    {
                        "reasonId":"c432f563-f835-4710-8055-5ee9e0fe1409",
                        "reasonName":"Some reason7"
                    }
                ],
                "orderItemName":"Item1",
                "orderItemId":961253,
                "hint":""
            }
        ]
    },
    "message":"OK"
}
```

I would like to fetch:

1. A list of all `reasonId` values under
   `responseData.orderLevelReasons`.
2. A list of all `reasonId` values
   under `responseData.productLevelReasons` where `orderItemId` is
   `961253` (as there could be productLevelReasons for multiple `orderItemIds`).

I Googled for this quite a lot and found that this can be achieved using `JsonPath`, but I could not figure out what exactly would be the JsonPath expressions for each of my purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A list of all reasonId values under responseData.orderLevelReasons

```
$.responseData.orderLevelReasons[*].reasons[*].reasonId
```

The [*] for orderLevelReasons is necessary if you want the reasons from all items in the orderLevelReasons collection. If not you can replace it with [0] and you can get a distinct list (assuming the same reasons repeat for each orderLevelReasons).

> A list of all reasonId values under responseData.productLevelReasons
>   where orderItemId is 961253 (as there could be productLevelReasons for
>   multiple orderItemIds).

```
$.responseData.productLevelReasons[?(@.orderItemId=='961253')].reasons[*].reasonId
```

This is also not distinct. You'll need to de-duplicate if duplicate reasons can exist.

> I validated both of your JsonPath expressions at
>   jsonpath.curiousconcept.com, both of them are valid. But the Java code
>   gives error for some reason.

I have looked into this. The rest-assured framework does not actually implement JsonPath, but a proprietary path based query syntax for JSON. Unhappily the name is the same but it is actually based on a completely different standard.

This [docs page](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) explains:

> Note that the JsonPath implementation uses Groovy's GPath syntax and
>   is not to be confused with Jayway's JsonPath implementation.

The JsonPath tag on StackOverflow is concerned with the [accepted](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) JsonPath specification, and not the rest-assured specification.

Based on my research I would conclude that the rest-assured jsonpath implementation does not support your requirement. You should use an implementation that does, such as [Jayway's one](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Comment: Thanks Tom! I'm trying to use the `JsonPath` expression in this way: `List<String> orderLevelReasons = new ArrayList<String>();
orderLevelReasons = jsonPath.getList("$.responseData.orderLevelReasons[*].reasons[*].reasonId");` but that gives an error `Invalid JSON expression`.

Comment: I validated both of your JsonPath expressions at https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/, both of them are valid and return expected outputs. But the Java code gives error for some reason. :(

Comment: Thanks Tom! I realised that I was trying with REST-Assured's JsonPath, but with Jayway's JsonPath your second expression gives valid output from my code, but the first expression returns an empty list.

Comment: I was trying with `List<Object>`. After trying with `List<String>`, it is working as expected. Thanks a ton Tom! I'd like to know how you derived the JsonPath expressions though. :)

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure - I read the spec ;). The string equality thing I just found by accident playing around. It makes sense that this should work like javascript string equality.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use groovy path you can use
`JsonPath.getList("path")` to fetch the data.

```
JsonPath.getList("responseData.orderLevelReasons.reasons.reasonId");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpzda.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OENOo.png)

Comment: add valid names for image urls

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) I also think you should learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). By the way - and pardon my ignorance - what is "groovy path" ?